# Count images from XML

Tags: php, xml, count

I am trying to run pull through an XML feed that shows the number of images relating to a property

```
console.log(type);
if (type == "buy"){
    var images = '. echo $images->count(); .';
} else{
    var images = 'No Images';
}
```

However I cannot get it to output right, can anyone help please?

Hope I've explained it right

I am expecting a number so if there are 5 images it will say 5 and I am currently getting `. echo $images->count(); .` which is just text, like it's unable to read it as PHP, when I try other ways I get undefined.

Comment: What output do you expect, and what do actually see? Can you provide a simple example?

Comment: Hi ewanc I am expecting a number so if there are 5 images it will say 5 and I am currently getting . echo $images->count(); . which is just text, like it's unable to read it as PHP, when I try other ways I get undefined

Comment: sorry I'm not very clued up with PHP, but I made a couple of edits to the question to hopefully make it easier for others to answer

Comment: @michi if i'm following right and apologies if not but is this what you mean?

'<images>
<image modified="2015-11-04 09:47:41">
URL
</image>
</images>'

Comment: sorry, misread your code. Please post all code necessary to understand where $images is coming from. Read "How to ask" in Help what to include in a question to get answers.